# Simulating Not Found Error In C HashTables

Tags: c, function, exception

I am learning data structures in my university and my choice of language is C. While I was implementing a Hash Table, I ran into somewhat of a hiccup with the C language. I am new to C, and from what I know the language does not support error throwing such as `throw new Exception()` in Java. I am trying to create a `get()` function that returns an integer value upon a successful find or indicates to the caller (without a run time error that causes the program to crash) that the value was not found. I need my table to support the full range of integer values so I cannot designate a special token value either.

I know that I could perform a search beforehand and then call the get() function if the search returned something other than `NULL` but I was hoping for a more elegant (one function call kindof) solution to this.

Also, I am hesitant in returning the Node of the List because I want to keep the implementation of the HashTable as abstract as possible therefore I want the interface of the Hashtable to only take in keys and return values. (I do not want to expose it's implementation)

```c
typedef int T;

typedef int Key;

typedef struct node_t {
    Key key;
    T val;
    struct node_t *next;
    struct node_t *prev;
}   Node;

typedef struct {
    Node *root;
    Node *tail;
    int size;
}   List;

typedef struct {
    int size;
    List **elements;
}   HashTable;


Node *search(List *list, T key) {
    if (list == NULL) return NULL;
    Node *current = list->root;
    while (current != NULL && current->key != key) {
        current = current->next;
    }
    return current;
}

T get(HashTable *table, Key key) {
    unsigned int index = hash(key) % table->size;
    Node *res = search(table->elements[index], key);
    if (res != NULL)
        return res->val;
    else {
        // What to do here!!!!!
    }
}
```

Please assume the other functions are implemented correctly, as I am more interested in how to solve this `get()` problem. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Give a *pointer to int* as an argument and return a `bool`

Comment: Wow. That was fast. Thanks a lot. I think that just might work.

Comment: In almost *all* practical uses of hash tables you can return a pointer though!

Comment: Do u mean a pointer to a Node or a pointer to the value (in this case `int *`)?

Comment: Either one... It really depends... probably a pointer to the value

Comment: Noted. Thanks for your help.